# How do you create a bar graph for a data frame in R that uses percentages as the y-axis instead of a count?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bigdata, data-manipulation

If I had a data from like this (but larger):

```
ID    Rating
12    Good
12    Good
16    Good
16    Bad
16    Very Bad
34    Very Good
38    Very Bad
52    Bad
```

What would I have to do to make a plot show the percent of the count of each type. Basically, the graph should look like 4 bars on the x-axis for each type of rating and the y-axis should be the percent of the time the rating appears. For example, the data frame above would have 4 bars with Very Bad and Bad being 25%, Good being 37.5% and Very Good being 12.5%. I would really prefer to get an answer in ggplot2, but, since I really can't find this at all, anything in R would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best answer I found:

```
# create data
data <- data.frame(ID = as.factor(c(12,12,16,16,16,34,38,52)),
               Rating = c("Good","Good","Good","Bad","Very Bad","Very Good","Very Bad","Bad"))

# get summary table of Rating
t <- table(data$Rating)
# get percentage list
percent <- as.vector(t)/nrow(data)

# plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data,aes(x=Rating)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
    ylab("Percentage") +
    ylim(0,0.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)

# create some data
DT <- data.frame(ID=1:10,Rating=sample(c("Very Good","Good","Bad","Very Bad"),20,replace=TRUE))

ggplot(DT, aes(factor(Rating))) + geom_bar()
```

Reference: [ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html)

Answer (score 1):

For showing proportions in base `barplots`, with actual proportions displayed as text over the bars:

```
tmp.table <- prop.table(table(dat$Rating))
with(dat, barplot(tmp.table, xlab= "Rating", ylab="proportion", ylim=c(0,.40)))
text(x = c(0.75, 2, 3.1, 4.25), y = tmp.table + .01, labels=paste(tmp.table*100,"%"))
```

**Result**

[image]
**Data**

```
dat <- read.csv(text="Rating
Good
Good
Good
Bad
Very Bad
Very Good
Very Bad
Bad")
```